# Dark matter ... could it be somehow be sound waves?

Tags: acoustics, dark-matter

I know that this sounds like a ridiculous question, silly even. But as they say, the only truly stupid question is the one not asked !

So how did I get to this thought.

Well I was reading stuff and watching a whole bunch of astrophysics documentaries over the last few weeks,I nerd out on this sort of stuff.

From nowhere I suddenly had a though that dark matter was sound !

So I've done a little looking around and come to the following questions / obvservations that I can't resolve on my own.

Both sound and light have a wavelength. However light is an electromagnetic wave and sound is mechanical (this I can understand, no problem here).

But could sound travel so fast that it could actually travel at the speed of light ? or could it travel very close to the speed of light, obviously it can't travel faster ;)

If this was possible what sort of medium would it need to be able to travel at that speed ? Maybe the answer to this is that dark matter supports sound travelling at close to 'light speed'.

This would explain partly why we can't observe it, as we generally attempt to observe the universe in the electromagnetic spectrum (radio wave, light waves ... etc etc).

I understand that we can detect sound above our range of hearing, as we do so with bats, and later convert it to something that we can 'hear'. but has anyone ever attempted to create a device that could capture sound moving at higher wavelengths ?

I understand that the speed of sound differs in different materials, so in air it is 332ms-1, in Hydrogen 1290 ms-1, in Steel 5960 ms-1, so it is possible that dark matter supports a speed of sound so fast that it goes beyond that which we can currently measure (or have simply not tried to measure).
I am also assuming that the frequency is extremely high too, making the job of detection even more difficult.
My assumption here is that if the wavelength could be so large, there is no reason that it shouldn't support an extreme frequency also.

I have no idea if any of the above could make any possible sense, I'm putting it here simply for the purposes of discussing the possibility.

I have no understanding of the effects of sound waves at such massively high speeds, or frequencies ... but if dark matter is __ everywhere ___ we could assume that evolution has been able to simply work around these problems, much like biology has worked around the problem of gravity (ie actin / myosin and leading eventually to muscles).

I understand that 'high energy' soundwaves (ie high / low frequency) can have quite remarkable effects on materials (and hence biology), but that is because what we are made of reacts to those frequencies and wavelengths.

What if the high speed sound is much like many other exotic particles (I'm thinking of the search for quarks and gluons etc) that they could simply pass through stuff 'undetected'.

As I say, I'm not sure if my thinking is totally woolly or not. I'm just throwing out the idea to see if anyone else has though of it previously.

Thanks in advance for your time reading such a 'stupid' question.

Comment: @NiharKarve : didn't suggest 'faster than light' I supposed 'light speed' (or something very close to it ! I suppose I could have been a little clearer and just said << light traveling at extremely high speeds getting close to the speed of light >> ... I'll edit my question just to clarify.

Comment: I'm not sure why this question has been voted down ? @NiharKarve did post a comment, to which I replied, and then edited the question. I notice his first comment is no longer visible ? I'm not overly concerned, just a bit bemused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certain possible forms of dark matter (e.g. gravitinos) would indeed be a medium for a kind of sound wave. But for dark matter to "be" sound waves...

Dark matter is whatever is supposed to be affecting stars on the edge of spiral galaxies, gravitationally warping the images of distant galaxies more than can be accounted for by visible matter, and causing a few other astronomical effects.

Normally the point of the dark matter hypothesis, is that these effects are caused by the gravitational field arising from the mass of the dark matter, en masse. It seems like your proposal would mean that these effects are to be attributed to dark sound waves, *instead of* the mass of the dark medium that they move through.

I won't say that such a thing is impossible, but it might require something unusual... There is an old theory of gravity, called push-gravity or the Le Sage theory of gravity, according to which the "pull of gravity" is actually due to being *pushed* by innumerable microscopic impacts of an unknown form of matter.

The theory is generally regarded as not working once you get into the details. But if it did work, maybe you could have a weird cosmology in which e.g. the pressure from the Le Sage particles is less than expected at the edge of galaxies, because of a ["termination shock"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heliosphere#Termination_shock) between a zone with dark sound and a zone without dark sound...

The reason I posited this in terms of the Le Sage theory, rather than conventional dark matter, is that gravitational influence due to the mass of the conventional dark matter, would surely drown out any effect from e.g. different densities on opposite sides of a shock front. It's because Le Sage gravity comes *directly* from dark matter pressure,  that there seems more scope for dark matter acoustics to be relevant, in such a theory.

Unfortunately the Le Sage theory has a lot of problems. But perhaps the ingenuity of today's legions of dark matter theorists could still produce a model in which dark acoustics matter more than dark mass, phenomenologically.

P.S. In order that you not be misled by these speculations, I would like to emphasize again that for there to be sound waves in dark matter is quite possible on the conventional view; but, conventionally speaking, these sound waves would not be responsible for the *observable effects* of the dark matter. Those effects would instead simply come from the gravitational attraction due to the dark matter's mass.

For an example of sound waves having a cosmic effect, see [baryon acoustic oscillations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baryon_acoustic_oscillations), sound waves in the primordial plasma which are believed to have left traces on the subsequent distribution of galaxies.

Comment: Thanks that is super interesting, if not for the actuall fact that dark matter could be sound waves, but that the idea has been thought about. I thought I was just being an idiot. Very cool. Also I like your thing about dark matter not ''be''ing sound waves. From reading your post I wonder if my thinking should have been << can we detect dark matter using ''sound'' somehow >>, I'm not sure if your response is a yes or no, as it seems some people are already thinking about this idea. which is cool .

Comment: So I've revisited this, and this explanation is my prefered one, hence I'm accepting it as the answer.
The universe is strange and weird == very cool.
Thanks to the other commenters and responders.

Answer (score 3):

The difference between sound waves and [electromagnetic waves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_radiation) is that sound needs a material on which the wave energy propagates sinusoidaly, whereas light propagates by itself in vacuum .  It has been verified experimentally that the [luminiferous aether,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminiferous_aether) a hypothesis of the 19th century trying to understand the propagation of light, does not exist in space around the earth. Electromagnetic waves propagate by themselves.

Sound waves cannot propagate in the vacuum of space, it is not possible to use sound the way you envisage. As  there exist [plasma in space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasma_(physics)), i.e. phase of matter composed of ions and electrons, sound waves can exist there, but not at the level of modeling dark matter, plasma is not dark.

Comment: Thanks, I am aware that sound can't travel in a vacuum. This is why I included the detail about sound moving at different velocities in different materiels. I think my hypothesis is that sound could move so fast in ''dark matter'' it would have odd effects. In much the same way that particles behave 'strangely' at the quantum level, why not sound behaving strangely at the 'near light speed' scale ?? Again the idea is to have the discussion, and expand my understanding. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: If dark matter is Weakly Interacting Particles, for example, certainly, as with plasma, sound could travel on it,but it would not be **the** dark matter